# difference between enumerated and structure in c language?

Tags: c

difference between enumerated and structure.

Comment: How to ask a question - http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: You're asking what the difference is between an `enum` and a `struct`? Wow…

Comment: Do you ask the difference between something enumerated and a structure? I think that a structure *is* something enumerated. It enumerates its members.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's a big difference.

Enumerations do not have members or attributes.

Structures do not define lists of constants. A structure can contain enumerations, but an enumeration cannot contain structures.

A structure:

```
struct Test {
    int a;
    float b;
    char c;
};
```

An enumeration (enum):

```
enum fruits {
    APPLE,
    ORANGE = 3,
    PEAR
};
```

Is this an interview question?

Comment: Sounds to me like someone was asleep in their first class of C Programming 101.

Comment: what, is that directed at me? I have never taken a programming course.